# Send Audio Data over the network using socket in c++

Tags: c++

Can any body tell me how can I packet audio data and send it to the client so the client can play the audio that has been received ? This is how the program start recording audio from microphone:

```
{
        waveOutReset (hWaveOut) ;  
        waveInReset (hWaveIn) ;  
        pBuffer1=reinterpret_cast <PBYTE> (malloc(INP_BUFFER_SIZE) );  
        pBuffer2= reinterpret_cast <PBYTE> ( malloc(INP_BUFFER_SIZE) );

        if (!pBuffer1 || !pBuffer2)  
        {  
            if (pBuffer1) free (pBuffer1);
            if (pBuffer2) free (pBuffer2);
            MessageBox (hWnd, szMemError, NULL,  
                        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK) ;  
            return TRUE ;  
        }  
        // Open waveform audio for input  
        waveform.wFormatTag      = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM ;  
        waveform.nChannels       = 1;  
        waveform.nSamplesPerSec  = 11025 ;  
        waveform.nAvgBytesPerSec = 11025 ;  
        waveform.nBlockAlign     = 1 ;  
        waveform.wBitsPerSample  = 8 ;  
        waveform.cbSize          = 0 ;  

        if (waveInOpen (&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER, &waveform,  
                        (DWORD) hWnd, 0, CALLBACK_WINDOW))  
        {  
            free (pBuffer1) ;  
            free (pBuffer2) ;  
        }  
        // Set up headers and prepare them  
        pWaveHdr1->lpData          = reinterpret_cast <CHAR*>( pBuffer1 ) ; 
        pWaveHdr1->dwBufferLength  = INP_BUFFER_SIZE ;  
        pWaveHdr1->dwBytesRecorded = 0 ;  
        pWaveHdr1->dwUser          = 0 ;  
        pWaveHdr1->dwFlags         = 0 ;  
        pWaveHdr1->dwLoops         = 1 ;  
        pWaveHdr1->lpNext          = NULL ;  
        pWaveHdr1->reserved        = 0 ;  
        waveInPrepareHeader (hWaveIn, pWaveHdr1, sizeof (WAVEHDR)) ;  

        pWaveHdr2->lpData          = reinterpret_cast <CHAR*>(pBuffer2 ) ;             pWaveHdr2->dwBufferLength  = INP_BUFFER_SIZE ;  
        pWaveHdr2->dwBytesRecorded = 0 ;  
        pWaveHdr2->dwUser          = 0 ;  
        pWaveHdr2->dwFlags         = 0 ;  
        pWaveHdr2->dwLoops         = 1 ;  
        pWaveHdr2->lpNext          = NULL ;  
        pWaveHdr2->reserved        = 0 ;  
        waveInPrepareHeader (hWaveIn, pWaveHdr2, sizeof(WAVEHDR));  
        }  
        break;
```

And this is the socket version where it accept, receive and send data:

```
switch(WSAGETSELECTEVENT(lParam))
{
    case FD_ACCEPT:
    if((new_socket = accept(wParam, NULL, NULL)) == -1){
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Error while accepting connection", L"Error", MB_OK);
    break;
    }
        // Prepare accepted socket for read, write, and close notification
    if(WSAAsyncSelect(new_socket,hWnd, WM_SOCKET,FD_READ|FD_WRITE|FD_CLOSE) == -1){
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Error while intialization", L"Error", MB_OK);
    break;
    }
                break;

    case FD_READ:  // Receive data from the socket in wParam

                break;

    case FD_WRITE:  // The socket in wParam is ready for sending data
    break;

    case FD_CLOSE:
            // The connection is now closed
            closesocket((SOCKET)wParam);
            break;
}
```

The problem is that I can't pack the audio data to send it to client and how the client is going to unpack again and play the audio

All replies are appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Why not using a streaming library like, says, gstreamer? http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-integration-win32.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably learning C++, and trying to take too many steps at once. Try recording to a file, and playing back a file. This will give you the sound-to-bytes and bytes-to-sound parts. Don't try to use a specific file format, just write and read raw audio data.